# When can a matrix be decomposed to a Hessenburg form vs Jordan Canonical Form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I understand that if a matrix is normal ($A^*A = AA^*$), then it is diagonalizable.
If it is not diagonalizable, then it has a Jordan canonical of form. 
However, a matrix can also be written as $A=Q^*HQ$ where H is a Hessenberg matrix.
Sounds like the Hessenberg reduction and Jordan canonical form is doing similar things to non-diagonalizable matrices.

Just wondering what is their difference and when one should use one vs the other.

Comment: Upper-Hessenberg form is numerically robust and tends to be useful in numerical applications.  Jordan canonical form is numerically unstable but very convenient for theoretical/formal computations

Answer (score 1):

The Jordan form is block-diagonal with triangular blocks, not merely triangular. It characterizes the matrix by its generalized eigenspaces. It is basically the next best thing to a diagonalization when you have a nondiagonalizable matrix, but it can at least in principle be used for the same purposes (for example, to compute matrix exponentials). In practice computing a Jordan form at all is often difficult (because a nondiagonalizable matrix "looks diagonalizable" to most numerical routines).

The Hessenberg form is not even really triangular, it has an extra diagonal that isn't filled with zeros. In the nonsymmetric case it is usually even dense (in the symmetric case it is tridiagonal, thus sparse). As far as I know it is almost exclusively used as a finite preprocessing step in algorithms for computing eigenvalues/eigenvectors (for example in the QR algorithm).

By the way, normality is necessary and sufficient for *unitary* diagonalization. It is not necessary for diagonalization in general.

Comment: Can I take it as two entirely separate factorizations? Does any square matrix have a jordan canonical form and a hessenberg form?

Comment: @user1559897 Yes.

Comment: But arent any square matrix have a schur decomposition as well? If we can decompose a matrix to a triangular matrix, why do we need the Hessenberg form?

Comment: @user1559897 Yes, though the Schur decomposition is also usually just a stepping stone to a diagonalization (because it is easy to diagonalize a triangular matrix).

Comment: @user1559897 This is the "finite" part. It is not possible to pass to the Schur form with a finite algorithm, whereas it is possible to pass to the Hessenberg form with a finite algorithm. Thus the abstract recipe is to go from A to the Hessenberg form of A (using a finite algorithm) to the Schur form of A (using an infinite algorithm) to the Jordan form of A (which can be done with a finite algorithm, but of course you had to make an approximation already in the previous step).

Comment: is it true that transform matrix A to the Hessenberg form, we use the Arnoldi iteration? What algorithm transforms the Hessenberg form to schur and to jordan form?

Comment: @user1559897 There are different ways to get the actual Hessenberg form, Arnoldi iteration is one of them. Converting from Hessenberg form to approximate Schur form is basically an eigenvalue solver such as the QR algorithm. Converting from a Schur form to a Jordan form is too trivial to become a named algorithm.